# How can subprocess be used in a class and tested in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, subprocess

I have an executable that has many options and I wish to create classes. e.g. the exec has options that can copy rows of a file, rename parts of a file, compress file, count specific rows of a file, e.t.c. Each option has parameters. I am uncertain if I am going about it the wrong way but I want to use oop.

```
import subprocess

class ExecProcess:
    def __init__(self, myfile, tempfile, outfile):
        self.myfile = myfile
        self.tempfile = tempfile
        self.outfile = outfile
        self.compressed_file = self.outfile + 'zip'

    def copy(self, myfile):
        temp_copy = subprocess.call(['executable', '-c', self.myfile, '-out', self.tempfile])
        return temp_copy # should this be return self.tempfile which is the output?

    def rename(self, myfile, tempfile, outfile): # need to include all the variables I declared in init?
        output = subprocess.call(['executable', '-i', self.myfile, '-r', self.tempfile'-out', self.compressed_file])
        return output # return self.outfile?
```

Given the above, how do I call the methods within the class and then write tests for them e.g using pytest. Its not intuitive to me how to test subprocess calls using pytest

The results of each call is a different file each time with each subsequent command taking the file from an earlier command as input. Please note, myfile is the only original file I have. tempfile and outfile are just variable names I assigned to the results.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `subprocess.call()` is definitely wrong here; probably try `subprocess.run()` or at least `subprocess.check_output()` if indeed you want to capture the output from the command.

Comment: modified exec to execprocess

Comment: Am I on the right track though. Also subprocess.call did work for me but I am not sure if the general idea I have is what the class should look like

Comment: Not sure what you are asking really. The code you posted looks like a Python wrapper for calling the subprocess rather than an actual test case. I'm not sure why you want to use Python to write a test suite but it could certainly be done. The comments look like they are related to how to design the wrapper, not the tests. The tests should obviously exercise whichever part you want to test, and of course you should probably test all of them (verify that the result is the expected one, that the file system has in fact been modified, that the command returns the expected exit code, etc).

Comment: If you use `subprocess.run()` the functions could actually return the resulting `CompletedProcess` object so that you can inspect the result code, standard output, and standard error from that.

Comment: Yes its a python wrapper. The question: is the way I wrote the wrapper correct? also I made some comments within the code itself as to what to return and if I need to include all the variables that I named instead of just the initial file. e.g in the rename function. Also if I am writing a test for it, how will the test look like? Do I need to include the subprocess call or just check to see if the file changed?  I will try subprocess.run()

Comment: I think you're asking too many questions or subquestions. Suggest you focus one on aspect that not working. SO isn't a software design service. It's mostly to help with specific programming issues.

Answer (score -1):

```
import subprocess

class Switch():

    def __init__(self, ip):
        self.ip = ip
        self.subproc = subprocess
    
    def ping(self): 
        
        success_ping = 0
        
        for i in range(3):
            status = self.subproc.call( ['ping', '-c', '1', '-W', '0.05', self.ip], stdout=self.subproc.DEVNULL )

            if status == 0:
                success_ping += 1   

        if success_ping > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_ip(self):
        return ('Switch IP: '+self.ip)

sw = Switch('192.168.1.1')

if (sw.ping):
    print('Switch', sw.get_ip(), 'UP')
else:
    print('Switch', sw.get_ip(), 'DOWN')
```

Maybe this be helpful for you